# How to install ant contrib under Windows?

Tags: ant

**Prelude:**
Ant-Contrib provides a very well explained wiki page for installation and launch ([http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/#install][1]).

Indeed, only two steps is necessary:
 - build ant-contrib-0.3.jar (by ant dist...),
 - move the built .jar into the lib directory of your Ant installation,

Use it by writing in your own project:

```
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties"/>
```

**My problem:**
I succeeded to build the .jar (build successful is written).
But I cannot find any "antcontrib.properties" in the jar built!

**Request:**
What is the important thing I have forgotten?
Is it better to search any ant-contrib-0.3.jar already built?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you download this file http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/ant-contrib-0.6.jar.zip, there's a antcontrib.properties contained. So maybe the installation instructions or the ant build file is out of date. Have you tried to use Maven for building the Ant-Contrib?

Comment: This link has been removed, so I cannot follow these instructions.  Can you find the newer link and replace this one?

Comment: the latest release of ant-contrib is on sourceforge: http://sourceforge.net/projects/ant-contrib/files/ant-contrib/1.0b3/

Answer (score 13):

if you have teh later 1.0b3 version.. 
from http://sourceforge.net/projects/ant-contrib/ 
or http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net

i beleive you have to use this one for ANT 1.6 and later :

```
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml"/>
```

instead of the antlib.properties file.

Answer (score 6):

I made a simple installer called [WinAnt](http://code.google.com/p/winant/) that will install Ant and Ant-contrib for you.

Answer (score 2):

I use my custom in-build.xml installer. This bad boy detects if you have it in your ant lib dir, then downloads and inits it if it's not.

All you need to do is add a depends="init-ant-contrib" to your target, and bam. You have ant-contrib whenever/wherever you deploy -- As long as sourceforge doesn't take away the dl link.

```
  <!-- ANT-CONTRIB autoinstaller -->
  <available property="ant-contrib-exists"
             file="${ant.library.dir}/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar" />
  <target name="download-ant-contrib" unless="ant-contrib-exists">
    <mkdir dir="${ant.library.dir}" />
    <get src="http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/ant-contrib/ant-contrib/1.0b3/ant-contrib-1.0b3-bin.zip?r=http%3A%2F%2Fsourceforge.net%2Fprojects%2Fant-contrib%2Ffiles%2Fant-contrib%2F1.0b3%2F&amp;use_mirror=cdnetworks-us-1"
         dest="${ant.library.dir}/ant-contrib-1.0b3-bin.zip"
         username="true" />
    <unzip src="${ant.library.dir}/ant-contrib-1.0b3-bin.zip"
           dest="${ant.library.dir}"
           overwrite="no" />
    <move todir="${ant.library.dir}">
      <fileset file="${ant.library.dir}/ant-contrib/*.jar" />
      <fileset file="${ant.library.dir}/ant-contrib/lib/*.jar" />
    </move>
    <delete file="${ant.library.dir}/ant-contrib-1.0b3-bin.zip" />
    <delete dir="${ant.library.dir}/ant-contrib" />
  </target>
  <target name="init-ant-contrib" depends="download-ant-contrib">
    <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties">
      <classpath>
        <pathelement location="${ant.library.dir}/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar" />
      </classpath>
    </taskdef>
  </target>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to download [ant-contrib-1.0b3](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ant-contrib/files/ant-contrib/1.0b3/) the latest version (1.0b5) does not contain ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar

Answer (score 1):

Here's the place you can find binary ant-contrib distributions: http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=36177&package_id=28636

Answer (score 0):

This should help :

```
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties" classpath="${lib.dir}/ant-contrib-1.0b3/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar"/>
```