# how to prepare ant-contrib-0.3.jar for ant contrib

Tags: ant, installation, ant-contrib

I have searched a lot and after following all these links...

[How to install ant contrib under windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653552/how-to-install-ant-contrib-under-windows)

[Apache ant-contrib](http://www.scmgalaxy.com/apache-ant/ant-ant-contrib.html)

[Using If-else in ANT](http://www.vincentkong.com/blog/-/blogs/if-else-in-ant)

[ant contrib @ Sourceforge](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/)

all I could generate is just only `cpptasks.jar` and nothing else.

Can anyone please guide me towards `ant-contrib-0.3.jar`?

Comment: http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/?

Comment: I have tried that also but it doesn't tell where to get the `jar`? I don't have the jar.

Comment: There is a [download link](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=36177) on that site. If you follow that through you get here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/ant-contrib/files/ant-contrib/ant-contrib-0.3/. Just download the bin.zip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On [ant-contrib.sourceforge.net](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) you can find a "downloads" link (somewhere in the middle of the text). This will lead you to the files section where you can find the archives for version 0.3: http://sourceforge.net/projects/ant-contrib/files/ant-contrib/ant-contrib-0.3/

Comment: I couldn't read between the lines to download the zip. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the jar file from:  http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadantcontrib03jar.htm