# Jenkins AntExec plugin not working with ant contrib

Tags: ant, jenkins

I have latest Jenkins running on Windows 2003 server. 
Under, manage Jenkins:
I have IBM JDK set 
I have ant: org.apache.ant_1.7.1.v20100518-1145 set as ant home
I have Jenkins AntExec plug in installed. 
I have ant-contrib-0.6.jar inside anthome/lib.

I created a job, and added  a build step, Execute Apache Ant, and I have this:

```
<echo> java home = ${JAVA_HOME}</echo>

<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml"/>
<project name="Test">

<description> Sample bulid file </description>
<target name="first">
<echo message="The first five letters of the alphabet are:"/>
<antcontrib:for list="a,b,c,d,e" param="letter">
  <sequential>
    <echo>Letter @{letter}</echo>
  </sequential>
</antcontrib:for>
</target>
</project>
```

when I run build, it fails.

```
antexec_build.xml:
     [echo]  ant home = ${ANT_HOME}
     [echo]  java home = ${JAVA_HOME}

BUILD FAILED
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\MCSOWelcome\workspace\antexec_build.xml:13: Problem: failed to create task or type project
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
```

I have tried many different things, no luck. Please suggest

Comment: Did you try relaunching your slave? The ENV variables that you set after launching the slave wont get reflected.

Comment: Have you set the _CLASSPATH_ environment variable to _%ANT_HOME%\lib_  Also try to add classpath to taskdef as shown in the post  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653552/how-to-install-ant-contrib-under-windows

Answer (score 0):

AntExec comes bundled with AntContrib. You do not need to add or define it. On the contrary, to *disable* it, you need to open 2 <kbd>Advanced...</kbd> dialogs before you get the option.

What you need to do though, is use `antcontrib` namespace.
For example, to use `for`, type:
`<antcontrib:for>`

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried it, but same result, see the code snippet above

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem (I got the same error message: `Problem: failed to create task or type project`), although I didn't use `<antcontrib:for>` tag.

If you type some code to the `Script source` field at the Project configuration > Execute Apache Ant, the plugin doesn't use it as an entire Ant script file, but it inserts into a template script. It appears if you choose to keep the buildfile (Advanced view at Execute Ant Build step). In this case the generated `antexec_build.xml` Ant script will not be deleted from the Workspace of the Project after the build.

The issue is reproducable with this simple script typed in `Script source`:

```
<project>
</project>
```

The generated `antexec_build.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project default="antexec_build.xml" xmlns:antcontrib="antlib:net.sf.antcontrib" basedir=".">

    <!-- Read additional properties -->
    <property file="antexec_build.xml.properties"/>

    <!-- Make environment variables accesible via ${env.VARIABLE} by default -->
    <property environment="env"/>

    <target name="antexec_build.xml">
        <!-- Default target entered in the first textarea - begin -->
        <project>
        </project>
        <!-- Default target entered in the first textarea -  end  -->
    </target>
</project>
```

So that, a solution would be that only include the Ant script that you intend to insert into the `<target></target>` tag.